# `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb when installing ruby and rubygems with rvm

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I was trying to create a fresh installation of Ruby and Rubygems using RVM on Ubuntu 13.10. I had already had an installation before which somehow got corrupted. I decided to reinstall everything, so I ran

```
rvm implode
```

which seemed to delete all traces of ruby and rubygems.

However, after reinstalling it using

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
source /home/<username>/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

when I run `gem install rails`, i get the following error:

```
<internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that my problem was the fact that I had created a symbolic link to `gem` manually in `/usr/bin`. After deleting the symbolic link, I reinstalled everything using the following commands:

```
rvm implode
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
source /home/<username>/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

after which

```
gem install rails
```

worked like a charm.