# Cannot find such file rubygems.rb when I go to create a new rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I seem to run into a problem when I go to create a new rails project via my cli terminal. I am on windows 8, but accessing a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS via remote connection with Putty.

Anyone know how to resolve this issue. Do I have two seperate paths to gem?

```
root@bullet:~# rails new entry_list
```

:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
        from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in`'

Comment: Have you taken a look at these two similar questions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310297/cannot-load-such-file-rubygems-rb and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23202620/require-cannot-load-such-file-rubygems-rb-when-installing-ruby-and-rubygem ? Are you using rvm on that ubuntu box?

Comment: How did you install Ruby?  First [google hit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310297/cannot-load-such-file-rubygems-rb) seems like it's probably your problem.

Comment: I have tried all of those suggestions on all of the links you posted. I installed ruby via the apt-get package. I tried to install the gem rails, but then I get an "activesupport requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3."

Comment: @Skram I tried installing rvm and it seemed to install, but then when I typed rvm install 2.1.0 I got an error "/usr/bin/rvm: No such file or directory
"

Comment: Since installing `rvm`, did you close your terminal and re-open it? There should have been some instructions about that our running a command starting with `source` to make the new installation available to your shell.

Comment: @Skram I closed my terminal and re-opened a new one, but never did the source command I don't believe. Let me close my current terminal and open a new one and do the source command.

Comment: @Skram, I did what said to do and I got this message: "root@bullet:~# source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
-bash: /root/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory
root@bullet:~#
"

Comment: Did you install rvm as root? You generally shouldn't...

Comment: @Skram, I did install it as root

Comment: @user1896756 sorry, I dont know